# Как найти натуральные трехзначные числа согласно условию задачи?

Tags: алгоритм, pascal

У меня есть задание:

> Найти все натуральные трехзначные числа, каждое из которых обладает
>   следующими свойствами:
>
> 1. первая цифра в три раза меньше последней его цифры;
> 2. сумма самого числа с числом, получающимся из него перестановкой второй и третьей цифр, делится на 8 без остатка.

я сделал только с первым свойством... со вторым не знаю как сделать...

```
var i,a,p,b,c,o : integer;
begin
  for i:=100 to 999 do
    if i div 100*3=i mod 10 then
      writeln(i);
end.
```

Comment: за что "-1"???  почему негативно так...мне же просто нужна помощ

Comment: Вы же смогли получить цифры числа - скомпонуйте из них "числом, получающимся из него перестановкой второй и третьей цифр". Ну и цикл имеет смысл не далее, чем до 399.

Comment: @Igor как? ........

Comment: Количество сотен * 100 + кол-во единиц * 10 + кол-во десятков

Comment: @Igor извините за назойливость...а кодом можете написать? как это должно быть.

Comment: а вы код сами писали? можете объяснить что именно в нем происходит?

Comment: @Grundy ну да) например число 600, 600 div 300 = 2 , 600 mod 10 = 0 . Если бы  результат от div , был равен результату mod , то вывело бы это число , тоесть 600.

Comment: а почему решили делить на 300? вам же первая цифра нужна и последняя

Comment: @Grundy потому что она в 3 раза меньше. если бы была в 5 , умножил бы 100 на 5

Comment: @Grundy Потому что он путает `(i div 100) * 3` и `i div (100 * 3)` - код, скорее всего, чужой.

Comment: @Igor, в первом случае тоже скобочки поставь чтобы уж совсем понятно было :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Не стоит решать задачу в лоб. Стоит немного подумать и применить математику. Нам известно, что первая цифра числа в три раза меньше последней. Значит она не может превышать 3. Последняя цифра это первая умноженная на 3. Значит нам надо попробовать числа от 1 до 3 для первой позиции и подобрать подходящую цифру для второй позиции.

Пусть первая цифра числа `i`, а вторая `k`, тогда второе условие задачи выглядит так:

```
сотни   десятки  единицы
i*100 +   k*10 + i*3  +  { само число }
i*100 + i*3*10 + k       { переставлены 2 и 3 цифры }
-----------
```

Упрощаем выражение:

```
(i*100 + k*10 + i*3) + (i*100 + i*3*10 + k) =
i*200 + k*10 + k + i*3 + i*30               =
i*200 + k*11 + i*33                         =
i*233 + k*11
```

Остается проверить делимость полученного выражения на 8.

```
var i,k : integer;
begin
    for i:=1 to 3 do
      for k:=0 to 9 do
         if (i*233+k*11) mod 8 = 0 then
           writeln(i*103+k*10);
end.
```

Comment: +1. Но в реальной жизни такой "умный" код нуждается в куче комментариев, поясняющих, что же он делает и почему )

Answer (score 1):

Давайте попробуем разобраться по шагам:

1. Нужно перебрать все трехзначные числа (забудем оп оптимизациях в угоду наглядности)
2. Для каждого числа нужно получить его 1 и 3 цифры
3. Надо их сравнить и решить подходят ли они условию
4. Аналогично надо обработать и второе правило:
5. Получить "второе" число поменяв 2 и 3 цифры
6. Сложить с числом и проверить остаток от деления на 8

С первым правилом вы с горем пополам разобрались. Посмотрим второе детальнее:

Как поменять в числе 2 и 3 цифры - мы снова разделяем число на цифры и собираем в другом порядке:

```
i_100 := i div 100; // сотни
i_10 := i div 10 mod 10; // десятки
i_1 := i mod 10; // единицы

i_new := i_100 * 100 + i_1 * 10 + i_10 * 1;
```

Проверить остаток от деления `i + i_new` вы надеюсь так же сможете сами.